# Div with a separator within it?

Tags: html

I'm new to Web design and I'd like to reproduce a classification of items as in the following snapshot:
[image]
As you can see, there's a nice "|" separator between the title and the description.
From the page source I can see it uses a div with a custom class attributes. I couldn't find a tutorial that shows how to reproduce a similar thing. Could anyone suggest the simplest way to produce a similar thing using a div,table or whatsoever?

Comment: why not use a border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a border on the section with css `border-style` You can adjust the width of your line with `border-width`
you can specify, in this order: top, right, bottom, left.
Check it out on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

```css
.rightBorder {
border-style: none solid none none;
border-width: 1px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightBorder"> JBoss </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have elaborated a table using the class you have provided. It looks like what I was looking for:    ` <table>  
        <tr>List of Elements
         <td style="border-style: none solid none none; border-width: 1px; height: 50px; width: 150px; color: blue;">Element 1</td>
         <td>Element 2</td>
        </tr>
             
    </table>`

Comment: Great news! Best of luck with your coding. @carla